# Open file from the command line on Windows

Tags: windows, command-line

On Mac OS X and GNOME on Linux, there are commands that can be used to open files from the command line in their associated GUI editors: `open` and `gnome-open`, respectively. Is there any command like this for Windows?

Comment: @badp: I mentioned "GNOME on Linux" not just Linux.

Comment: Whoops, sorry.

Comment: @badp: No worries. ;)

Comment: xdg-open is the more universal Linux example, if anybody cares

Answer (score 68, accepted):

If you are currently in the command prompt and have a file called `test.png` and , which are located in `c:\test` you can do the following:

If you are at the directory (so should say `c:\test>`) just type:

```
test.png
```

which would open test in the default png picture editor.

If the files name contains spaces, then simply enclose the file name within " "

```
 "this image.png"
```

You can alternatively type:

```
c:\test\test.png
```

which will open the file no matter where you currently are.

Finally, you can pass the picture to another program. For example, if you have an image editor called imageedit.exe and it supports opening files through command lines (and if the program is pathed/accessible or you are in it's current directory), you can type the following:

```
 imageedit c:\test\test.png
```

Comment: Just curious: is there also a way to close files or programs or windows through command prompt?

Comment: @MilesJohnson only by calling other tools such as taskkill.exe

Comment: works from cmd, but not from PowerShell or Git Bash  - explorer is the more universal way

Comment: It's interesting to know that this works for sure! That said, I don't like it! It would be quite confusing to see just a png filename listed as a "command" in a script when you aren't aware of this trick.  It would appear like someone screwed up and forgot the executable name they meant to invoke.

Answer (score 70):

If it is a registered extension, you can use "start" as in

```
start WordDoc.doc
```

Comment: Good answer for those using Bash or another shell.

Comment: This is actually the correct answer. It even opens the default browser if you supply a URL.

Comment: When I enclose the name in quotes, it instead opens a new shell window for some reason.

Comment: As Steven Digby mentions below start's first parameter is the window title so something like `start "" WordDoc.doc` would work

Comment: start does different things depending on the shell you use.

With Powershell, it invokes Start-Process
With cmd it invokes the tradional start
With Git Bash, it invokes the cmd Start


The cmd Start does not handle network locations.
The PowerShell version will, as will 'explorer ' as detailed below.

Answer (score 16):

On Windows command-line `explorer "<PATH>"` will open the file path with Windows default associated programs. This will also handle all URIs ( http:,https:,ftp: ) and other file protocols defined in Windows Operating System.
If the file or protocol is not associated with any program then an `Open With` dialog will show up. If file is not present then default `My Documents` folder will open up. It can also open executable files ( EXE, BAT files) and  shell namespace paths.

**Examples**

`explorer "http://www.google.com"`- will open http://www.google.com in windows default browser.

`explorer "file:///C:\temp\"` will open *temp* directory if present

`explorer "file.txt"` will open `file.txt` on the current directory path .i.e. `%CD%` path

`explorer ::{645ff040-5081-101b-9f08-00aa002f954e}` will open *RecycleBin*.

You can refer about explorer's other useful command-line switches [here](http://www.geoffchappell.com/studies/windows/shell/explorer/cmdline.htm)

Answer (score 5):

```
powershell -c "folder\childfolder\file.txt"
```

Source: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176882.aspx

Simple and versatile.

Answer (score 3):

The first parameter of Start is a window title, so if you have a space in the file name, and you type

Start "My File.txt"

you'll get a command line window with "My File.txt" as the title. To get around this use a dummy title,

Start "my title" "My File.txt"

Depending on the file and what application is opened there probably won't be a window to see anyway.

Comment: `start` is a `cmd.exe` built-in operator. Meaning it is unavailable in `exec` library calls or in Windows `CreateProcess`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are *in* PowerShell
(at the `PS (current-directory)>`  prompt),
and you want to open a file in the current directory,
you may try this `.\myfile.ext`. 
If you are in the Command Prompt, you can accomplish the same result by typing

```
powershell -c .\myfile.ext
```

(You must include the **`.\`**,
as PowerShell doesn’t load files from the current location by default.) 
Or you can provide a directory name (relative or absolute)
if the file isn’t in the current directory.

For the first scenario — if you are *in* PowerShell —
if the filename contains space(s),
enclose it in quotes (either kind) and precede it with
the  **`&`** symbol:

```
PS C:\Users\myusername\Pictures> &".\funny cat.jpg"
```

(You may add a space after the `&` for readability,
if you prefer readability, and you may use `/` instead of `\`.) 
I don’t know how to make this work in the second scenario
(in which you are running `powershell -c` from Command Prompt)
if the file or directory name contains space(s) — quotes don’t seem to help.

Answer (score -1):

This may come a bit late, but the correct command for editing a file name in Windows 7 is "write file_name"

This should open up the default text editor and you should be able to edit the file easily

Edit: It seems to open only Wordpad. For me that was the default text editor.

Comment: Nice trick. It does not start the default text editor however. My default editor for .txt files is Crimson editor, but this command opens Wordpad.

Comment: Yes, it does so for me too. Wordpad was default for me. Thanks for the update! Regardless, hope this helps the original poster.

Comment: `write` is short for `write.exe` which is the executable file of wordpad. It's stored in `C:\windows` which is on the `%PATH%`, therefore it's just the regular way to open a file with wordpad.

Answer (score -1):

**Specific** executable with **specific** file:

**Git Bash** Script On **Windows 10** :

---

## SHORTCUTS_MAIN_START.sh :

```
    FILE_PATH="C:\DEV\REPO\GIT\AHK03\SHORTCUTS\SHORTCUTS_MAIN.ahk"
    EXEC_PATH="C:\DEV\REPO\GIT\AHK03\AHK_ROOT\AutoHotkeyU64.exe"

    $EXEC_PATH $FILE_PATH
```

---

This example opens the file denoted by $**FILE_PATH** with the executable denoted by $**EXEC_PATH**. If this doesn't work for you, try converting the single slash ( "\" ) into double slashes ( "\\" ) for the paths.

Answer (score -3):

In the Windows command prompt, you can run

```
edit [file_name]
```

in order to view batch files/logs/text files etc. This command requires `QBASIC.EXE`, which is by default present in Windows.

See [here](http://www.sophos.com/en-us/support/knowledgebase/13195.aspx) for other useful MS-DOS commands.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work on Windows 7 64-bit, neither `edit` nor `qbasic.exe` are recognised. Also, this only works with plain text files.

Comment: @Indrek, Not recognized on Win8 too.

Comment: Modern Windows command line is NOT DOS.